I have completed the registration process in Django user login, but I want the login process to check and match the tokens. How can I do this
I created a user login with Django. I used tokens during the registration process, and I want the user to be redirected to the homepage if the tokens match when they enter their password during login.
I want to implement user login with tokens in my Django project
